# What is the unit for the oil quantity display in the Airbus A320 ECAM?

Tags: airbus-a320

[image: image showing the 'engine' page of the ECAM display of an A320, with indications of fuel used, oil, presure, temperature and other info.]

Is this image showing 18.5 liters or quart of engine oil? It is from an Airbus A320 with CFM 56-5B engines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is actually in the image: Below "OIL", it says "QT", which according to the "Abbreviations" table under "General Information" in the A320 FCOM, means

> Quart (US)

[image]

Comment: Thanks You. You are great

Comment: Probably they use this unit because as it is close to liter (0.94), they don't have to change anything for the european market, except the label.

Comment: @Legisey I think the European market also uses quarts, not liters. It wouldn't make sense for a European made plane which is used by airlines around the globe and potentially flies intercontinental with pilots from all over the globe to have separate displays for different markets, especially in the risky manner you describe where they only replace the unit but don't redo the calculations.

Comment: A bigger question is *why* do they use US Quarts for oil? Or more broadly how have we ended up with such a mix of US and metric units (and possibly imperial for all I know).  I was going to ask but it's too close to [Why doesn't the aviation industry use SI units?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2572/2559), thoughg the accepted answer there states *Non-SI is only used for altitude, distance and speed except in US and some other American countries.* which doesn't seem to be the case here

Comment: Yes. The capacity of tank for overflow oil is 20.1 quart. And why i uplift full oil, it only show 18.5. There are logical about it?

Comment: The ECAM engine oil quantity indication corresponds to the "useable" oil quantity in the
engine oil system
The difference between "total" and "useable" oil quantities is around 5 US quarts.